# "tight fitting" circle node with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's a minimal tikz figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That circle around the 'A' is bigger than I'd like. I want it to look more like this. (The 'A' is meant to be the same size as in the previous image, and the circle smaller.)

[image]

How can I achieve that? There are several previous questions about changing the size of a node, but they seem to be either about the size of an empty node, or making it bigger, which can be achieved with `minimum size` or `inner sep`. (I'm unsure about what these commands do or what the difference is, but they don't seem to be what I want.) My goal is just to specify the radius of the node exactly, regardless of the size of its label.

The circle is a node in a graph, and should behave as a node of the correct size when connecting arrows to it and so on.

I guess I could just write a `\newcommand` to draw an empty node of the correct size and then write the label on top of it, but it feels like that's not the intended way to use tikz, so I'm wondering what the proper way is.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is here. Do you not understand `inner sep` or do you want an alignment?

Comment: @AndréC as a matter of fact, when I posted this I didn't understand `inner sep`. (I said so in the question.) But that isn't the point, necessarily. I want the node to have a specified radius, independently of the label's bounding box, that's all.

Comment: With TikZ, a `node` is a box that contains text. This default box is rectangular. If it perfectly frames the text, the edges of the box touch the text, which is unattractive. By default TikZ leaves a space between the text and the edges of the box which is defined by the length `ìnner sep` (initially is 0.3333em).

When the node is a circle, this circle is circumscribed to the rectangular node which is drawn by default. 
Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Answer (score 4):

To obtain a perfect alignment whatever the letter used, you must set the `height` and `depth` of the text:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    circled node/.style={circle,draw, inner sep=0, minimum size=1.5em},
    better circled node/.style={circled node,text height=.8em,text depth=.25em},
  }
  \foreach \letter[count=\c] in {A,B,H,Q,Z,a,f,g,É}{
    \path (\c*6mm, 0) node [circled node] (N-\c) {\letter};
    \path (\c*6mm, -1) node [better circled node] (M-\c) {\letter};
  }
  \draw[red,very thin,dashed] (N-1.base) -- ++(5cm,0);
  \draw[red,very thin,dashed] (M-1.base) -- ++(5cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well this was easier than I thought. One must combine the mysterious invocations `inner sep` and `minimum size` in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw, inner sep=0, minimum size=1.5em] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It looks weirdly off centre, but I'll live with that.

I imagine there's a reason why this works, and that it's written somewhere in the 1000 page manual. I wish I lived in a world in which I had time to read it.

Comment: `Circle` has also a parameter `radius`, witch should make it even easier

Comment: @Cube I forgot to mention that in the question: `radius` seems only able to make the circle bigger than the default, not smaller. It probably works as expected with some combination of `inner sep` and `minimum size`, I'd imagine.

Comment: interesting, i didnt know that. `\draw circle[radius=5pt] node{A};` would be how i do it and there it works no problem

Comment: @Nathaniel  -- `invocation` thats hilarious  like black magic haha

Comment: @Cube The `circle` node shape does not have a `radius` parameter, what you're using there is the `circle` path constructor, they are not the same. The way you do it there is no connection between the size of the circle and the size of the node, but with `\node [circle,draw] {foo}` the circle will always be bigger than `foo`.

Comment: Nathaniel, the `inner sep` is the distance from the content of the node to the node border. When you say `\node [circle, inner sep=0] {A};` you get a circle that circumscribes the rectangle that is the bounding box of the `A`. With `\node [circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=1.5em] {<stuff>};` you'll get a circle with a diameter bigger than or equal to `1.5em`, depending on the size of `<stuff>`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I see. So technically my solution doesn't work, I was just lucky that the bounding box of the 'A' was smaller than 1.5em. This is probably fine for the figure I'm drawing, but do you know a way to do what I actually want, which is to set the radius to exactly 1.5em, regardless of the size of `<stuff>`? I'd prefer the size not to change if the bounding box of the content happens to be slightly larger than 1.5em.

Comment: (`minimum size` sets the diameter, not the radius.) Well if you use Cube's suggestion you can do that, but if `<stuff>` becomes too large, it may go outside the circle. I don't really know a good solution.